# Rails 4 - either or if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I have an organisation model, which has an attribute called `org_type`. In my organisation form, I ask users to specify whether their org type is university, college or other kinds of organisation. In my show page, I want to show some text if the org type is university or college.

I can't get the either or function working. If I just ask to check one org type, such as below, it works fine:

```
<% if @organisation.org_type == 'University' %>
```

If I ask for either org type, it shows everything even where the test org is 'other':

```
<% if @organisation.org_type == 'University' or 'College' %>
```

The above doesn't work. It shows the text where the org type is 'other'.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic in the view like that risks getting complex and hard to maintain. It always starts as just one check for those couple of conditions, then gets copied to half-a-dozen places, then the condition changes to "uni, college or self-study" and you've got to find all the places you used it.

Better to extract it to a method in the model, and then have the views just ask the model.

```
# Organisation model
def uni_or_college?
  %w(University College).include? org_type
end

# view
<% if @organisation.uni_or_college? %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This is also a testable approach - if you have tests that ensures the `.uni_or_college?` method returns what's expected, if (when) the requirements change in future, you have a safety net to help with your refactoring.

Comment: Taking this one step further down the maintainable code route, it would be nice to extract the constants used in the uni_or_college? method into a proper constant which could then be referenced. HIGHER_EDUCATION = %w(University College). def uni_or_college?; HIGHER_EDUCATION.include? org_type; end.

Comment: Pavling's answer is excellent. This is what I do as well. I use to write them like.... if ["University", "College"].include?(org_type) ...... or pre-build the array like Institutions.where(:type => [......]).select(:type).collect{ |i| i.type } if I want the list built from existing records

Comment: @margo or as SubClasses of the Organisation model - replacing conditional with type. But one step at a time :-)

Answer (score 2):

rails actually runs below if condition as two separate conditions.

```
<% if @organisation.org_type == 'University' or 'College' %>
```

`@organisation.org_type == 'University'`  is true **OR** `'College'`.

means, `<% if (@organisation.org_type == 'University') || ('College') %>`

To overcome this situation, you can do something like that:

```
<% if ['University', 'College'].include?(@organisation.org_type) %>
```

It would return **true** if `@organisation.org_type` is either 'University' or 'College'. Else **false**